# 5-level HLM analysis

Tags: r, lme4

I am trying to analyze a hierarchical structure of five different levels at which student ratings of teacher might be aggregated.

Teacher ratings are collected from the students enrolled in each class each semester.

The ratings **(level1)** are nested within students **(level2)**, who are themselves nested within sections **(level3)** or classes **(level4)**, which also nested within the higher levels of the hierarchy.

Can the `lmer` function or other functions handle such an analysis?

If yes, what is the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the levels are truly nested as suggested by the question (i.e. *not* cross-classified: every rating is done by exactly one student, every student is in exactly one section, every section is in exactly one class ...), then the specific answer is that you want to include

```
(1|class/section/student/rating)
```

as the random-effect term in your `lmer` model.

If you have more levels you can use extended versions incorporating higher levels, e.g.

```
(1|toplevel/nextlevel/nextlevel2/.../bottomlevel)
```

As @Alex suggests, this is described in the vignette (Table 2, on p. 6), although it only shows two levels of nesting in the example.

@Alex also suggests that your data might be cross-classified - students might provide ratings in more than one class - in which case you might want to add additional terms, e.g.

```
(1|class/section/student/rating) + (1|student)
```

would allow for consistent effects of students across different classes and sections.

The `lme` function (in the `nlme` package) can also handle arbitrary numbers of nested levels, although dealing with cross-classification is harder (and it is likely to be slower than `lmer` for large data sets).

Answer (score 2):

Let's define some notation, which you don't provide in your post:

`Y` = ratings 
`ID` = student id 
`section` = class section 
`class` = class

I'm also assuming that you're saying students are *cross-classified* between classes and sections. In `lme4`, we typically assume cross-classification is independent.

You then have:

```
lm1 <- lmer(Y ~ <FE vars> + (1|class/ID) + (1|section/ID), data= df)
```

Here we use `/` to denote levels of the hierarchy (eg. `section/ID`) with higher levels to the left of the slash. more levels would be `XYZ/section/ID`. Additionally, the different `()` elements show cross classification. You can alternatively use `(class || section)` And `(1|...)` indicates random intercepts but no random slopes.

#### Note:

All of this information is in the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf), which you are encouraged to read.